# Derive anonymous dsa key-pair from two certificate authorities

Tags: signature, certificates, anonymity

Is it possible to derive a dsa key-pair based on two private keys from different/independent "Certificate Authorities" (ca1 and ca2) to sign s.th. which then verifies only that the signature is a child of ca1 *and* ca2 but not which of the keys, that have been originally issued by the ca's has been used? Thus anonymized signature?

```
ca1 = certificate authority 1
ca2 = certificate authority 2
cert1 = public certificate of ca1
cert2 = public certificate of c2
privkey1 = private key issued by ca1
privkey2 = private key issued by ca2
privkey = getprivkey(privkey1, privkey2) = private key derived from ca1 & ca2
datasig = signature of data package - signed with privkey
dsaproof = digital signature algorithm proof function
```

Is the following possible?

```
True = dsaproof(datasig, cert1)
True = dsaproof(datasig, cert2)
```

Comment: So would you write down equations you'd like to verify?

Comment: not private keys are associated with CAs but public keys.

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych I dont have an equation but instead wanted to find out, if there is the possibility to do so.

Comment: @Cryptostase True, but in order to create a new key-pair which is related to two other key-pairs I need to use private keys, otherwise anyone could generate children based on public keys. And further, the signature of the new key-pair should then prove that the key-pair is inherited from ca1 _and_ ca2. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don’t understand why the _CA_  should be anonymized in the first place.

Comment: @Cryptostase Its not about the CA's. They're public and thats ok. The individual owning a key derived of the CA's should be anonymized.

Comment: @Techradar  Lets pretend a new key-pair was created. What equations are there for that key-pair and other known stuff?

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych added an equation - is this what you were looking for?